# Surface attribute only calculated for actual points and not interpolated

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, surface

When I run the surface hillshade, slope and aspect in the Arc Toolbox using my raster surface it appears to be calculating the attribute only for the data points and not for the interpolated areas between. I loaded the points as a XYZ file then used Feature to Raster to create the surface.

Comment: Interpolate points to raster first